# SpringFox docket add request parameter to specific end point

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I am using [springfox](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/) to generate swagger urls for [rest end points](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I have a specific rest endpoint that does not require a request parameter on the controller level, but requires request parameter on a [filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that pre-handles the request.

I want to define a request parameter on the [Docket](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html) in the Docket definition and not on the controller because annotating parameters on the controller makes it really dirty and hard to read.

In other words, i want to define swagger parameter without using [ApiImplicitParams](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParams.html), and instead define it on the Docker.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using the `globalOperationParameters` method on the Docket builder.

```
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    ...
    .globalOperationParameters(
        newArrayList(new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("someGlobalParameter")
            .description("Description of someGlobalParameter")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
            .parameterType("query")
            .required(true)
            .build()))
```